# how to prove by contradiction that any distance between a curve $x^4 - x^2 + y^4 - y^2 = 0$ and the origin is less than or equal to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given a closed trajectory $x^4 - x^2 + y^4 - y^2= 0$
Prove that any distance between any point on the curve and the origin does not exceed $\sqrt2$ (ie, maximum distance from the origin to the curve is $\sqrt2$)

I proved it using polar transformations but i'd rather use proof by contradiction without using polar transformation, so i tried

$$\begin{array}{l}
\left( {\exists \alpha ,\beta } \right){\rm{ }}{\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}>2\\
{\alpha ^4} - {\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^4} - {\beta ^2} = 0\\
 \Rightarrow {\alpha ^4} + {\beta ^4} = {\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}\\
 \Rightarrow {\left( {{\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}} \right)^2} - 2{\left( {\alpha \beta } \right)^2} = {\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}{\rm{ }}\left( {{\rm{Completing - Square}}} \right)\\
 \Rightarrow {\left( {{\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}} \right)^2} = {\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2} + 2{\left( {\alpha \beta } \right)^2}\\
 \Rightarrow {\left( {a + b} \right)^2} = a + b + 2ab \le 2\left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right){\rm{ }}\left( {{\rm{Cauchy - Schwarz - Inequality}}} \right)\\
 \Rightarrow a + b \le \left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right) + \left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right) - 2ab\\
 \Rightarrow a + b \le \left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right) + {\left( {a - b} \right)^2}\\
 \Rightarrow {\left( {a - b} \right)^2} \ge \left( {a + b} \right) - \left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right) \ge 0\\
 \Rightarrow \left( {a + b} \right) \ge \left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right)\\
 \Rightarrow \left( {{\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}} \right) \ge \left( {{\alpha ^4} + {\beta ^4}} \right)\\
 \Rightarrow \left( {{\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}} \right) - \left( {{\alpha ^4} + {\beta ^4}} \right) \ge 0
\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaadaqadaqaaiabgoGiKiabeg7aHj
% aacYcacqaHYoGyaiaawIcacaGLPaaacaqGGaGaeqySde2aaWbaaSqa
% beaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaeqOSdi2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaO
% GaaGOmaaqaaiabeg7aHnaaCaaaleqabaGaaGinaaaakiabgkHiTiab
% eg7aHnaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiabek7aInaaCaaale
% qabaGaaGinaaaakiabgkHiTiabek7aInaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaa
% kiabg2da9iaaicdaaeaacqGHshI3cqaHXoqydaahaaWcbeqaaiaais
% daaaGccqGHRaWkcqaHYoGydaahaaWcbeqaaiaaisdaaaGccqGH9aqp
% cqaHXoqydaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcqaHYoGydaahaa
% WcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaacqGHshI3daqadaqaaiabeg7aHnaaCaaa
% leqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiabek7aInaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaa
% aaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgkHiTiaa
% ikdadaqadaqaaiabeg7aHjabek7aIbGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaale
% qabaGaaGOmaaaakiabg2da9iabeg7aHnaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaa
% kiabgUcaRiabek7aInaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiaabccadaqada
% qaaiaaboeacaqGVbGaaeyBaiaabchacaqGSbGaaeyzaiaabshacaqG
% PbGaaeOBaiaabEgacaqGTaGaae4uaiaabghacaqG1bGaaeyyaiaabk
% hacaqGLbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaeyO0H49aaeWaaeaacqaHXoqy
% daahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcqaHYoGydaahaaWcbeqaai
% aaikdaaaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGH
% 9aqpcqaHXoqydaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcqaHYoGyda
% ahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaaIYaWaaeWaaeaacqaHXoqy
% cqaHYoGyaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaacq
% GHshI3daqadaqaaiaadggacqGHRaWkcaWGIbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWa
% aWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaeyypa0JaamyyaiabgUcaRiaadkgacq
% GHRaWkcaaIYaGaamyyaiaadkgacqGHKjYOcaaIYaWaaeWaaeaacaWG
% HbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaamOyamaaCaaaleqaba
% GaaGOmaaaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaiaabccadaqadaqaaiaaboeacaqG
% HbGaaeyDaiaabogacaqGObGaaeyEaiaab2cacaqGtbGaae4yaiaabI
% gacaqG3bGaaeyyaiaabkhacaqG6bGaaeylaiaabMeacaqGUbGaaeyz
% aiaabghacaqG1bGaaeyyaiaabYgacaqGPbGaaeiDaiaabMhaaiaawI
% cacaGLPaaaaeaacqGHshI3caWGHbGaey4kaSIaamOyaiabgsMiJoaa
% bmaabaGaamyyamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiaadkgada
% ahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaacqGHRaWkdaqadaqa
% aiaadggadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaWGIbWaaWbaaS
% qabeaacaaIYaaaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyOeI0IaaGOmaiaadgga
% caWGIbaabaGaeyO0H4TaamyyaiabgUcaRiaadkgacqGHKjYOdaqada
% qaaiaadggadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaWGIbWaaWba
% aSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaGaey4kaSYaaeWaaeaaca
% WGHbGaeyOeI0IaamOyaaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOm
% aaaaaOqaaiabgkDiEpaabmaabaGaamyyaiabgkHiTiaadkgaaiaawI
% cacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHLjYSdaqadaqaaiaa
% dggacqGHRaWkcaWGIbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyOeI0YaaeWaaeaaca
% WGHbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaamOyamaaCaaaleqa
% baGaaGOmaaaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabgwMiZkaaicdaaeaacqGHsh
% I3daqadaqaaiaadggacqGHRaWkcaWGIbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyyz
% Im7aaeWaaeaacaWGHbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaam
% OyamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaaqaaiabgkDi
% EpaabmaabaGaeqySde2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaeq
% OSdi2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyyzIm7a
% aeWaaeaacqaHXoqydaahaaWcbeqaaiaaisdaaaGccqGHRaWkcqaHYo
% GydaahaaWcbeqaaiaaisdaaaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaacqGHshI3
% daqadaqaaiabeg7aHnaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiabek
% 7aInaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabgkHiTmaa
% bmaabaGaeqySde2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaI0aaaaOGaey4kaSIaeqOSdi
% 2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaI0aaaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyyzImRaaGim
% aaaaaa!4654!
$$

Since the last equation includes 0, I cannot show any contradiction.
I think the problem is that I did not use my hypothesis, ${\alpha ^2} + {\beta ^2}>2.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaeqySde2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaO
% Gaey4kaSIaeqOSdi2aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaaGOmaaaa!34DD!
$

I think this claim can be proven using contradiction by I'm just not sure how to use my hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution. Use Lagrange multipliers for $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ with the constraint $$g(x,y) = x^4 - x^2 + y^4 - y^2 = 0.$$ Putting $\nabla f(x,y)$ and $\nabla g(x,y)$ in rows: $$\begin{vmatrix} x & y \\ 2x^3 - x & 2y^3-y\end{vmatrix}=0 \implies xy^2-yx^3=0.$$ If $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ (the trivial case), we get $y = \pm x$. Back to $g(x,y) = 0$. $$x^4-x^2+x^2-x^2 = 0 \implies 2x^4-2x^2=0 \implies x^2-1 = 0 \implies x = \pm 1.$$ So we get the points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. And $f(1,1) = f(1,-1)= 2$. So the square of the maximum distance is $2$, hence the maximum distance is $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$0 = x^4-x^2 + y^4-y^2 = \left(x^2-\dfrac12\right)^2 + \left(y^2-\dfrac12\right)^2 - \dfrac12 \implies \left(x^2-\dfrac12\right)^2 + \left(y^2-\dfrac12\right)^2 = \dfrac12$$
I trust you can finish off from here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using Power Means or QM-AM inequality:
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}2 \le \sqrt{\frac{a^4+b^4}2} = \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}2} \implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le \sqrt2$$

Comment: Nice and simple way of finding contradiction!